# PHP com object doesn't showing content correctly for non English character

Tags: php, com-object

I am struggling with php COM object, to read (.doc) word data. Problem is while i am retriving content from doc file, data is showing but it's not showing actual data -

#### example.doc content

Čo je to zubný povlak?
Zubný povlak je lepkavá a bezfarebná vrstva baktérií a cukrov, ktorá sa neprestajne tvorí na povrchu zubov. Býva hlavnou príčinou zubných kazov a parodontitídy a ak sa denne neodstraňuje, môže stvrdnúť a zmeniť sa na zubný kameň.

#### php

```
$filename = 'example.doc';
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object.");
$word->Documents->Open(realpath($filename));

// Extract content.
$content = (string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content;

echo nl2br($content);

$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);

$word->Quit();
$word = null;
unset($word);
```

#### result is showing

Co je to zubný povlak?
Zubný povlak je lepkavá a bezfarebná vrstva baktérií a cukrov, ktorá sa neprestajne tvorí na povrchu zubov. Býva hlavnou prícinou zubných kazov a parodontitídy a ak sa denne neodstranuje, môže stvrdnút a zmenit sa na zubný kamen.
Ako zistím, že mám zubný povlak?

Like `Čo` is showing `Co` instead of `Čo`

Any help is highly appreciated or is there any other way to read doc file (not docx) which will show character perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maybe an error with the encoding (is your text in utf8 ?).

As per the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) (look for the codepage param), you can set a code page as the third argument.
For exemple with utf8 :

```
$word = new COM("word.application", NULL, CP_UTF8) ;
```